# How do I get IP of an EC2 instance in node.js syncronously?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to get the IP associated with an EC2 instance.  However, when I try to access the variable it doesn't exist at that point.  How do I get it to retrieve the IP first before printing it out?

```
const getIP = async () => {
  await ec2.describeInstances(params, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      return err
    }
    return data.Reservations[0].Instances[0].PublicIpAddress
  }).promise(); 
}

const ip = getIP();
console.log(ip);   // Returns null here
```

I need to call the function multiple times in different places, so I don't want to put the IP variable inside the async await function.

Comment: why dont you shift your variable ip inside async function and use await so that you always get the value of IP.

Comment: I need to call the function in different places, so I can't put the IP inside the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this issue, I wrapped the function in a promise.

```
function getIP(){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
ec2.describeInstances(params, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      reject(err)
    }
    resolve(data.Reservations[0].Instances[0].PublicIpAddress)
  })
}
}

const ip = await getIP()
```

Answer (score 0):

try this approach

```
const getIP = async () => {
  await ec2.describeInstances(params, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      return err
    }
    return data.Reservations[0].Instances[0].PublicIpAddress
  }).promise(); 
}
```

Since getIP() is an async function when console.log is called, getIP() has not finished yet, so ip is still not assigned. The following code will call console.log after getIP() was done.

```
const show = async () => {
 const ip = await getIP();
 console.log(ip);
}
show();
```

now you can use show() function to get your IP or return the IP value in different places, the same thing can be achieved using global vairbale but its not recommended

Answer (score 0):

Use `await` when calling an `async` function:

```js
const getIP = async () => ec2.describeInstances(params, (err, data) => {
    if (err) return err
    return data.Reservations[0].Instances[0].PublicIpAddress
  }).promise()

const ip = await getIP()
console.log(ip)
```